# url is not identifying the id passed in form action

Tags: php, forms

i have a search form whose action attribute contains an id to be passed in the URL and form is submitted from get method for user to get the search results to be shared or bookmarked.

Now the problem i am facing is, that id i have passed in action is not displaying in the URL but all other input field's values are appearing fine.

This is my form:

```
<form action="trails.php?pname=<?php echo $getName;?>" id="filter" method="GET" name="filter">
    <select class="multiselect form-control" multiple="multiple" name='activity[]' id="activity">
       <?php
          $toaSql = mysql_query("select * from type_of_activity where cat_id='1'");
          while ($toaRow = mysql_fetch_array($toaSql)) {
          echo "<option  value='" . $toaRow['typeOfActivity'] . "'><img style='width: 21px; margin-left: 5px;' src='home/images/" . $toaRow['catImg'] . "'> " . $toaRow['typeOfActivity'] . "</option>";
        }
      ?>
  </select>

  <select class="multiselect form-control" multiple="multiple" name='activity[]' id="activity">
      <?php
         $toaSql = mysql_query("select * from type_of_activity where cat_id='2'");
                                        while ($toaRow = mysql_fetch_array($toaSql)) {
                                            echo "<option  value='" . $toaRow['typeOfActivity'] . "'><img style='width: 21px; margin-left: 5px;' src='home/images/" . $toaRow['catImg'] . "'> " . $toaRow['typeOfActivity'] . "</option>";
                                        }
                                        ?>
                                    </select>
       <select class="multiselect form-control" multiple="multiple" name='activity[]' id="activity">
                                        <?php
                                        $toaSql = mysql_query("select * from type_of_activity where cat_id='3'");
                                        while ($toaRow = mysql_fetch_array($toaSql)) {
                                            echo "<option  value='" . $toaRow['typeOfActivity'] . "'><img style='width: 21px; margin-left: 5px;' src='home/images/" . $toaRow['catImg'] . "'> " . $toaRow['typeOfActivity'] . "</option>";
                                        }
                                        ?>
                                    </select>
</form>
```

trail.php page:

```
if(isset($_GET['pname'])){

 $getName = $_GET['pname'];
 // print_R($getName);
if($getName=='video'){
    $queryVideo = "SELECT * FROM `contributevideo` WHERE status='active' " ;
    //echo $queryVideo;
}elseif($getName=='album'){
    $queryAlbum = "SELECT * FROM `contributeimage` WHERE status='active' AND category='album'" ;
}
```

}

Trails.php page run the sql queries according to the page name it gets from the url, but in url its not finding any `pname` variable so the queries are not executing.

Where i am doing wrong please guide.
Thanks

Comment: why dont you use a hidden field in your form?  `<input type='hidden' name='pname' value='<?= $pname ?>'  />` and in your **Trails.php** use `if(isset($_POST['pname']))`

Comment: How you are submitting this form?

Comment: i am using the get method to post the form, then why are we accessing the variable in trails from `$_POST['pname']` ?

Comment: @Geetika sorry,, than you should use `$_GET`.. but use hidden fields only. dont pass the get variable in form action.. :)

Comment: @Geetika where is your submit button?? How's the form is getting submitted?

Comment: its there in the form....i just havent put it in this code here

Comment: @Geetika you get success with the hidden field?

Comment: If `$getName` is an input variable, you should definitely escape it when you output it in HTML. In fact, that goes for anything that you output in HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you describing parameter as URL-encoded?

```
<form action="trails.php?pname=<?php echo $getName;?>" id="filter" method="GET" name="filter">
   // Existing form
```

Since your form's method is 'GET', you can just describe a hidden input.

```
<form action="trails.php">
   <input type="hidden" name="pname" value="<?php echo $getName; ?>"/>
   // Existing form
```

It should work.

Comment: @Geetike Debug the code then. Try putting "print_r($_GET)" in the beginning of trails.php to get the contents of GET array on execution.

Comment: its showing me the form field's value i entered except the hidden field

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your code is that you set the form to submit the values using the `GET` method. This means that the values from the form fields will be passed in the URL, overwriting (removing) your `pname` value.

To fix it just change the `method` of the form to `POST` and the PHP code to access `activities` through `$_POST['activities']`, it should work then.

Comment: i wanted to display all the field's value in url that is why i used the GET method..